# Convert a List to an unmanaged array for C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, list, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm creating a .NET wrapper class to a C++/CLI function. Internally the function uses an array of ints (`int*`), but I'd like to expose a clean `List<int>^` on the .NET side. I'm using the following code to convert a C# List to a C++ unmanaged list of int.

Apart from the fact that I'm not freeing the allocated memory using `Marshal::FreeHGlobal`, is there any problem with the function? For example, should I be allocating `((count * 4) + 4)` for the array length bytes?

```
static int* ListToArray(List<int>^ list){

    // new array
    int count = list->Count;
    int* arr = (int*)(Marshal::AllocHGlobal(count * 4).ToPointer());

    // convert list to array
    for(int a = 0; a < count; a++){
        arr[a] = list[a];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. You allocate the correct amount of memory. Instead of `4` I would use `sizeof int`, which is more expressive.

I do wonder why you are using `AllocHGlobal`. I think `new` would be more appropriate in C++ code. And I also wonder why you are using raw pointers. Wouldn't `std::vector<int>` makes more sense in C++ code?